# Learn Python The Hard Way - ex18

Tags: python-3.x

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print ("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % arg1, arg2)

def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):

def print_one (arg1):
    print ("arg1: %r" % arg1)

def print_none():
    print ("I got nothing.")

print_two ("Zed", "Shaw")
print_two_again ("Zed", "Shaw")
print_one ("First!")
print_none()
```

File "ex18.py", line 7
def print_one (arg1):
  ^
IdentationError: expected as indented block

- I forgot to type in the arguments on print_two_again... should be `print ("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2))"`

Comment: Method/functions definitions cannot have an empty body, but `print_two_again()` is empty. Add [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement). Also it would be nice if this had an actual question in it.

Comment: Don't add answers to the question - if you now have an answer, write it up yourself *an an answer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, where you're formatting strings with more than one argument (in fact, I do this even if there's only *one* argument), you should have parentheses around the arguments. So change:

```
print ("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % arg1, arg2)
```

into:

```
print ("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2))
```

Secondly, if you want a function (or loop or some other thing that needs a statement) to do nothing, you should generally the `pass` keyword, such as:

```
if pi == e:
    pass
```

However, in this case, if you actually go back to the book, you'll see that `print_two_again()` is implemented thus:

```
def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2)
```

In other words, you seem to have missed out a line when transcribing the code.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I did forget to add the arguments in the function print_two_again. I dont know how I managed to do that, probably a little confusing to see with all the prints. ;)